# How to create a symlink to root

Tags: command-line, filesystem, symbolic-link

I want to create a symlink to the root (`/`) folder in my home directory.
However if I try this, I get

```
~$ ln -s /
ln: failed to create symbolic link './': File exists
```

I can do this using Nautilus <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, of course, so I know it's possible.

How to do so using the terminal?

Comment: While this is a good question, I want to know the reason why  you would want do to this?  Is it too hard to type in `cd /`?  Or do you like to create a link that would keep going through a loop over and over and over again?  example:  `cd root/home/terrance/root/home/terrance/root/home/terrance/root` . . . etc.

Comment: not really .you could do this without needing to link to root . actually, i was just curious why you can't do it

Comment: Fair enough.  Thank you for answering my question.  =)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You're missing the name of the link, it should be:

```
cd ~
ln -s / root
```

Which then would create a symlink called root in your home directory. So the correct usage is:

```
ln -s <target> <link-name>
```

The error message you see is, that `./` always exists and a link can not be created with this name, best is to use the [`ln` command](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/ln)<sup>2</sup> with both parameters to prevent wrong linkage.

From [`man ln`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/ln):

> > **SYNOPSIS**
> >
> > ```
> > (1st form) ln [OPTION]... [-T] TARGET LINK_NAME  
> > (2nd form) ln [OPTION]... TARGET  
> > (3rd form) ln [OPTION]... TARGET... DIRECTORY  
> > (4th form) ln [OPTION]... -t DIRECTORY TARGET...
> > ```
> >
> > **DESCRIPTION**
> >
> > > In the 1st form, create a link to *`TARGET`* with the name *`LINK_NAME`*. In
> > >          the 2nd form, create a link to *`TARGET`* in the current directory. In the
> > >          3rd and 4th forms, create links to each *`TARGET`* in *`DIRECTORY`*. Create
> > >          hard links by default, **symbolic links  with `--symbolic`. By default,
> > >          each destination (name of new link) should not already exist**<sup>4</sup>. When
> > >          creating hard links, each *`TARGET`* must exist. Symbolic links can  hold
> > >          arbitrary text; if later resolved, a relative link is interpreted in
> > >          relation to its parent directory.
> > >
> > > Mandatory arguments to long options are mandatory for short options
> > >          too.
> >
> > [**OPTIONS**](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/ln)

The final parameter, `<link-name>`, defaults to the last part of the target. So when the target is `/path/dir` the link name will default to `dir` if not specified.<sup>1</sup> And if you for example create `~/etc` with `mkdir ~/etc` and then run `ln -s /etc` in `~` it can not create the link because the name/directory already exists.<sup>3</sup>

And you can see the link created in your home directory (here as example, of course you're free to name it whatever you like):

```
$ ls -l ~/root
lrwxrwxrwx 1 videonauth videonauth 1 Dez 14 00:28 root -> /
```

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Thanks to [@thomasrutter](https://askubuntu.com/users/54256/thomasrutter) for pointing that out.</sub>
<sup>2</sup> <sub>See also [`man link`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/link) and [`man symlink`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/symlink)</sub>
<sup>3</sup> <sub>Thanks to [@steeldriver](https://askubuntu.com/users/178692/steeldriver) for providing an example in comments.</sub>
<sup>4</sup> <sub>Emphasised part to make text point out since it is relevant to the question.</sub>

Comment: my only remaining doubt is why should a command like `ln -s /etc` work but not this one? Thanks for the answer,

Comment: It is created because it has a directory name, `/` can be root or it can be a path component so the program can not know what now is meant. `/etc` is just an explicit distinguishable path.

Comment: @AnkurSonawane because `./` will *always* exist - `./etc` not so likely. Try `mkdir etc` first, and then `ln -s /etc` - you will also get `File exists`

Comment: The final parameter, link-name, defaults to the last part of the target if omitted.  So when the target is `/some/dir` the link name will default to `dir` if not specified.  When the target is just `/`, however, this isn't going to work.

Comment: I don't feel that this extremely significant but @steeldriver 's explanation sounds more reasonable given the `File Exists` output. Not that it matters anyway as this is the degenerate case